# Action Method does't Called on Jquery Dialog oad

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog

I am calling a controller method from my javascript function to load in Jquery Dialog box,but control does not go to Controller method,Dialog opens up,but the partial view that i have called from Controller method doesn't open in Dialog box.Even call doesn't go to controller action method.

**Control Goes to createNewSetClick when i click the button,but it doesn't call Action method OpenCreateNewSetDialog in My Controller "ClaimAuditAdminController"**

```
 function createNewSetClick() {
            debugger;
            $("<div></div>").appendTo("body").load("/ClaimAuditAdmin/OpenCreateNewSetDialog")
            .dialog({
                modal: true, title: STATICPOPUPTITLE
            })

        }
```

Comment: Your action method wouldn't happen to expect parameters which you maybe forgot to supply?

Comment: it's parameter less method

Comment: Have you checked the request in your browser developer tools (F12) network tab, or in fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you refactor your code to this.. im not sure wether this will help but i dont like calling .appendTo and .load on the same line.

```
function createNewSetClick() {
            debugger;
            var $div = $("<div></div>");
            $('body').append($div);
            $div.load("/ClaimAuditAdmin/OpenCreateNewSetDialog");
            $div.dialog({
                modal: true, title: STATICPOPUPTITLE
            })

        }
```

if still the action method isnt being called check whther the url is correct and mention the error you you are getting when sending the request